# Recommender System (SVD) with TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, recommendation-engine, collaborative-filtering

I'm trying to create a collaborative filtering algorithm to suggest products to certain users.

I started shortly and started working with TensorFlow (I thought it was sufficiently effective and flexible).
I found this code that does what I'm interested in, creates the model and train the user IDs, products, and ratings: https://github.com/songgc/TF-recomm

I launched the code and trained the model.

After training the model I would need to make the predictions, that is, get suggestions for each user so that they can be saved in a DB from which I access with a NODE.js application.

How do I retrieve this list of suggestions for each user when the training is done?

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    df_train, df_test=get_data()
    svd(df_train, df_test)
    print("Done!")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to modify the prediction part of your code to output `top K` recommended products. The current code where the prediction is made is :

```
 embd_user = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(w_user, user_batch, name="embedding_user")
 embd_item = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(w_item, item_batch, name="embedding_item")
 infer = tf.reduce_sum(tf.multiply(embd_user, embd_item), 1)
```

Here the `embed_user` is the user embeddings of a particular user and `embd_item` is for the particular item. So instead of comparing a `particular user` with a `particular item`, you need to change it to compare it to all items. The matrix `w_item` is the embeddings of all items. This can be done by:

```
 embd_user = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(w_user, user_batch, name="embedding_user")
 # Multiply user embedding of shape: [1 x dim] 
 # with every item embeddings of shape: [item_num, dim], 
 # to produce rank of all items of shape: [item_num]
 predict = tf.matmul(embd_user, w_item, transpose_b=True)
```

Then you can select the `top k` index of the maximum in the predicted output.

Comment: Ok perfect. I have an error on embedding_lookup when I use my DB data having an alphanumeric id instead of an int32, the error is: "TypeError: Value passed to parameter 'indices' has DataType string not in list of allowed values: int32, int64". How can I fix it?

Comment: Can you tell me which line the error is?. And what is 'DB data'? In embedding_lookup what is the input your changing that causing this error?

Comment: One of the lines which causes the error: "embd_user = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(w_user, user_batch, name="embedding_user")".  
This is because the ids that load from my database are alphanumeric and not int32: https://www.dropbox.com/s/9s4vxsciue3mu38/Schermata%202017-07-08%20alle%2010.32.48.png?dl=0.
Then the user batch has type tf.string:  "user_batch = tf.placeholder(tf.string, shape=[None], name="id_user")"

Comment: You said you were able to train the network. How it work by giving the input  id as  string?. The code link you shared has `user_batch = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[None], name="id_user")` , if your data is of string, then for each `user  ID` assign a unique ID (int) and then feed it to the network.

Comment: I trained him with a test dataset and now I'm trying to link it to my DB.
So can i not use the alphanumeric ids of my DB? Do I have to map them with integers for example with a hasp map and then redraw them out of the box?
Thanks for the help, I apologize for my inexperience in this field.

Comment: No problem.. i understand.You can't have two different user data for train and test. The set should be same. The train creates the embeddings matrix for the user/item, and the test just reads from it. The ids will be used as a index to the embedding matrix array, that why it should be `int`.  Your integer ids should be an index to an Matrix array. So assign [1, 2....N]  for N users.

Comment: OK thanks, I will only use DB as dataset. So I have to assign [1, 2 .... N] for N users and [1, 2 ..... M] for M items and in the output convert from integer to original alphanumeric id, is correct As a solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can run

```
predict_result = sess.run(inter_op, feed_dict={user_batch:users, item_batch:items})
```

which users means all user ids and items for all item ids, and predict_result is the scores of each user for all items, you can store the predict_result into DB;

Comment: So if I have to find the 10 recommended products for each user, do I have to manually combine all products with every user and then find the top 10? Does not there be a more efficient way?

predict_result = sess.run(infer, feed_dict={user_batch: [users[0], users[0], users[0] .........], item_batch: [items[0], items[1], items[2] ................]})